# JS Fetch Event Data and Display in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fullcalendar, fetch-api

I'm fetching some event data and I would like to display this in a [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

I am able to fetch the data and display it using `colsole.log()`, I'm just not sure what to do after that.

The calendar expects the data to be in the following format;

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    { // this object will be "parsed" into an Event Object
      title: 'The Title', // a property!
      start: '2018-09-01', // a property!
    }
  ]
})
```

I have a `function` that fetches the data (two test events on Eventbrite), see below;

```
const token = 'mytoken';
const url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/events/?&expand=venue';

function getEB() {
    let fetchData = {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }),
    }
    fetch(url, fetchData)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        // get the number of events
        var numEvents = data.events;
        numEvents.forEach(function(element) {
            var title = element.name.text;
            var start = element.start.local;
        });
        console.log(data); 
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

When I call the function `getEB` I can see [this response](https://pastebin.com/9wUfLVaS) (copied to paste bin due to size) in the console Network response tab.

What do I need to do with my code in order to return results in the correct format? I need to be able to access the `title` and `start` variables within that function.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . Hopefully you get the idea. Let me know if you tried something based on that and encountered an issue

Comment: Ok so just to narrow it down to the specific issues, so we can give you the best and quickest help...what  exactly didn't you understand in the link I provided? Did you attempt to implement the idea? What went wrong? Can we see your attempt?